# How to integrate java application with tally Erp 9

Tags: java, tally

I am New to tally. I created one web application in java. How to  get values from java application and update in tally software.

Manually i created masters and ledgers and groups in tally but i want to create master form java web application

please help me out!

Comment: I want update transactions in tally form java application